# App Crash with exc_bad_access code

Tags: ios, exception, exc-bad-access, appdelegate

Let me introduce my functionality of App,I use push notification & addressbook and `CoreTelephony` Framework.

What I am doing in my application is , When i get Push notification, I save the number from the Payload in a Appdelegate Variable(Incoming_NO) , if there is no Such contact with this number , Ill create the new contact and save it. 
                                                                                                       When i receive the Call , the same contact name appears as i added before , Later on I am allowing the user to Edit the Contact if he want to save the contact or to delete , When he edit the contact and later when i receive the Push notification with same number I am getting the **exc_bad_access** to (Incoming_NO) I have enabled the Zombie and i got the breakpoint error at the same place ..

Can anyone help me what is the issue .

```
    Received notification: {
        aps =     {
            alert = "Please help me-+918884718240";
            sound = "beep.caf";
        };
    }
```

Code :

```
 NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];

 NSRange range=[alertValue rangeOfString:@":"];
    NSString *param,*msg;
    NSRange range1=[alertValue rangeOfString:@":"];
    if (range1.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        param = [alertValue substringFromIndex:range1.location + range1.length];

        msg=[alertValue substringToIndex:range.location + range.length-1];
    }
    else
    {
        range1=[alertValue rangeOfString:@"-"];
        if (range1.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            param = [alertValue substringFromIndex:range1.location + range1.length];

            msg=[alertValue substringToIndex:range1.location + range1.length-1];
        }


    }
if(range.length!=0)
    {
        parts= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[alertValue componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]];

    }else
    {
        parts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[alertValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]];
    }

incoming_Number =[parts objectAtIndex:1];
```

For this Variable(incoming_Number) I get the error when i receive the Push notification after saving the contact.

I tried to change **incoming_Number** type to NSString and NSMutableString , still the same error , I guess what happening is I am referring to the object which is released . But in debugger I can see it has the value.

Adding Contact Code:

```
- (void)setContacts:(UIImage *) imgdata :(NSString *)incoming_number {


ABRecordRef person=NULL;
ABRecordRef loopingPerson=NULL;
_Bool vizzical_present=false;
CFErrorRef myError = NULL;
NSArray *allContacts;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &myError);
//    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);

__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    //dispatch_release(sema);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
   //     int count = (int) ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);


   allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray
                            *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

  for(CFIndex i = 1; i < allContacts.count; i++)
    {

        loopingPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];

        CFStringRef firstName;
        // char *lastNameString, *firstNameString;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(loopingPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        if([(__bridge NSString *)(firstName) isEqualToString:@"VizziCal"]){
            vizzical_present=true;
        }
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(loopingPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        //     NSMutableArray *numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       // CFStringRef phoneNumberLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex( phoneNumbers, 0 );
        CFStringRef phoneNumberValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex( phoneNumbers, 0 );
        NSString* noSpaces =
        [[(__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        if(phoneNumberValue!=NULL){
        NSString* noHypen =
        [noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
       // CFStringRef phoneNumberLocalizedLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel( phoneNumberLabel );
       // NSString *addPlus=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",incoming_number] ;

            if([incoming_number isEqual:noHypen] || ([incoming_number rangeOfString:noHypen].location!=NSNotFound)){
       NSLog(@"%@  and %@ and %ld",incoming_number,noHypen,i);
                person=loopingPerson;
            break;

            }
        }

    }

    if(person!=NULL){
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
        NSData* imageData1 = (__bridge NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)(imageData)];

        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)(imageData1)];


    NSData *dataRef;
    UIImage  *mergedImage;
    if(image!=NULL)
    {
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   savedImagePath= [self saveImage:image1 forPerson:@"image"];

                 });


        dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgdata);

        CFRelease(imageData);
    }
    else{

        if(imgdata.size.height <480 && imgdata.size.width<320)

        {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image.png"];


        mergedImage=[self mergeTwoImages:imgdata :image];


        CGFloat width = imgdata.size.width;
        CGFloat height = imgdata.size.height;

        NSLog(@"Height:%f and Width =%f",width,height);
        dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mergedImage);
        }

        else{

         dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgdata);
        }

    }
    CFDataRef cfDataRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);

    if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error);
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

    }
    //ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Don Juan", NULL);

    // ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &error);

    if (ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfDataRef, &error)) {
        if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {
            NSLog(@"has unsaved changes");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"nothing to save");
        }
        if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error)) {
            NSLog(@"saved");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"not saved");
        }
    }

    }

    else{

        if(!vizzical_present)
        {
        ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();

        ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"VizziCal", &myError);

            CFDataRef dataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgdata));
            [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"contact-created"];


        //Phone number is a list of phone number, so create a multivalue
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =
        ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(incoming_number),kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
   // ...
            // Set other properties
            ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, &myError);
            // ...
            ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, newPerson, &myError);



        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &myError);

        if (myError != NULL)
        {
            CFStringRef errorDesc = CFErrorCopyDescription(myError);
            NSLog(@"Contact not saved: %@", errorDesc);
            CFRelease(errorDesc);        
        }



        if (ABPersonSetImageData(newPerson, dataRef, &myError)) {
            if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {
                NSLog(@"has unsaved changes");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"nothing to save");
            }
            if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &myError)) {
                NSLog(@"saved");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"not saved");
            }
        }

        CFRelease(newPerson);
        CFRelease(addressBook);

        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }
        else
        {
            ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();


            for(CFIndex i = 1; i < allContacts.count; i++)
            {

                loopingPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];

                CFStringRef firstName;
                // char *lastNameString, *firstNameString;
                firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(loopingPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                NSString *name=(__bridge NSString *)(firstName);

                if([name isEqualToString:@"VizziCal"])
                    break;



            }
            if(loopingPerson !=NULL )
            {
                      [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"contact-created"];

                    CFDataRef dataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgdata));


                    //Phone number is a list of phone number, so create a multivalue
                    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =
                    ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(incoming_number),kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
                    // ...
                    // Set other properties
                    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, &myError);
                    // ...
                    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, newPerson, &myError);


                    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &myError);

                    if (myError != NULL)
                    {
                        CFStringRef errorDesc = CFErrorCopyDescription(myError);
                        NSLog(@"Contact not saved: %@", errorDesc);
                        CFRelease(errorDesc);
                    }



                    if (ABPersonSetImageData(newPerson, dataRef, &myError)) {
                        if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {
                            NSLog(@"has unsaved changes");
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"nothing to save");
                        }
                        if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &myError)) {
                            NSLog(@"saved");
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"not saved");
                        }
                    }

                    CFRelease(newPerson);
                    CFRelease(addressBook);

                    CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);

            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Here what I am doing is , I am checking whether Person Exist or not , if not I am checking for the default contact "VizziCal" if that doesnt exist then I am creating the New contact as "VizziCal".

Comment: App Crash with exc_bad_access due to you are release objcet and then still it is in used that's why this error happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Crash with exc\_bad\_access code Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396173/app-crash-with-exc-bad-access-code-exception)

Comment: Do not post the same question multiple times!

Comment: error where i get , that object still exist i can see in debugger

Comment: @Kerni My question is not yet solved ..

Comment: @JitendraDeore I did , there are some potential leaks how to i solve it ?

Comment: used (nonautomic,retain) where you leak happen

Answer (score 0):

First Rather doing all this stuff for getting `Incoming No`, Try **Custom Payload for this**.

It is simple.

Take a look [Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

you could try:

```
{ "alert": "Please help me", "phone": "9999999999" }
```

**NOTE: This will created at server side.**

Comment: I am getting the Payload take a look at below :                                         Received notification: {
    aps =     {
        alert = "Let us talk-+918884718240";
        sound = "beep.caf";
    };
}

Comment: i know what you get. now from this you are getting number, but rather doing that use custom payload. so in it there will not problem of crash or any object release.

Comment: But how to call didReceiveRemoteNotification? without Push ?

Comment: tell right now how do you get `Received notification: { aps = { alert = "Let us talk-+918884718240"; sound = "beep.caf"; }; }` this??

Comment: But for same payload its working fine for first iteration , when i add the contact and for next iteration am getting error , may be something released .

Comment: I am getting Push , and its working fine for first iteration with same payload...

Comment: Can u please help me solving this ?